# Update specific records of MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am dealing with phone system and have to work with multiple service vendors. For one vendor I have a MySQL table `country_codes` like this -

```
---------------------------------------------------------
country_code  |  area_code  |  country
---------------------------------------------------------
93            |  93         |  Afghanistan
0             |  9375       |  Afghanistan Cellular-AT
0             |  9370       |  Afghanistan Cellular-AWCC
355           |  355        |  Albania
0             |  35568      |  Albania Cellular-AMC
0             |  35567      |  Albania Cellular-Eagle
213           |  213        |  Algeria
0             |  21377      |  Algeria Cellular-Djezzy
0             |  2135       |  Algeria Cellular-Wataniya
---------------------------------------------------------
```

and so on...

The country_code column wasn't there before but I added it since I needed it for my PHP application. I managed to update the country codes for some records (using answer from my previous question here)

What I want to achieve is to replace the 0's with the respective country code. So the table should look like this -

```
---------------------------------------------------------
country_code  |  area_code  |  country
---------------------------------------------------------
93            |  93         |  Afghanistan
93            |  9375       |  Afghanistan Cellular-AT
93            |  9370       |  Afghanistan Cellular-AWCC
355           |  355        |  Albania
355           |  35568      |  Albania Cellular-AMC
355           |  35567      |  Albania Cellular-Eagle
213           |  213        |  Algeria
213           |  21377      |  Algeria Cellular-Djezzy
213           |  2135       |  Algeria Cellular-Wataniya
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I hope I explained myself well enough. Any idea how can I do that with PHP-MySQL ?

*(I don't mind using PHP code to manipulate the table this way)*

Comment: You can use the relation between area_code and country_code to populate the country_code(Part of area_code is your country_Code)

Comment: I need a little more info.  How can we tell what makes a valid country code?  Since they're sometimes 2-digit and sometimes 3-digit, we can't just chop off the end of the area code.  Do you already have all valid country codes entered at least once throughout your 28,000 records?

Comment: It looks like each "company" has an area code that begins with the area code assigned to the "country," correct? Does this pattern work with the whole dataset?

Comment: @Andrew Yes all records have valid country codes already entered

Comment: @Sachyn What types are `country_code` and `area_code`... `int`, `varchar`?

Comment: @ Michał Powaga both are `int`

Comment: @Sachyn based on that I've changed my answer, have you checked it? I can't test it but seams ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE country_codes
SET country_code := @c := IF(@c IS NOT NULL AND country_code = 0, @c, country_code)
ORDER BY CAST(area_code AS CHAR)
```

Comment: country_code can be minimum of 1 digit and maximum of 4 digits

Comment: SUBSTRING(area_code, 1, 3) won't return more then 3 chars(digits). It also will return empty string in case of empty `area_code`. Do you have empty `area_code`?

Comment: +1, Can you please explain the query. I do not understand the @c part

Comment: @Naveen Kumar - @c is a user variable, we go through the records with specific ordering, and set field value and that variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
update cc set
    country_code = t.country_code
from country_codes cc
join (
    select country_code, country, char_length(trim(cast(country_code as char))) as code_len
    from country_codes
    where country_code <> 0
) t on 
    t.country_code = cast(substr(cast(cc.area_code as char), 1, t.code_len) as signed integer) and
    cc.country_code = 0 and
    cc.country like concat(t.country, '%')
```

I've added `cc.country like concat(t.country, '%')` to condition to be more specific but it assumes that each cellular network name starts with its country name - so if it's not true omit it.

**Added** after @Sachyn comment:

Test code used on [SQLZOO](http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/tip915069/mysql) works fine, **it is for testing only, it's not an update query**:

```
select cc.*, t.country_code as new_country_code
from (
    select 93 as country_code, 93  as area_code , 'Afghanistan' as country union
    select 0  , 9375 , 'Afghanistan Cellular-AT' union
    select 0  , 9370 , 'Afghanistan Cellular-AWCC' union
    select 355, 355  , 'Albania' union
    select 0  , 35568, 'Albania Cellular-AMC' union
    select 0  , 35567, 'Albania Cellular-Eagle' union
    select 213, 213  , 'Algeria' union
    select 0  , 21377, 'Algeria Cellular-Djezzy' union
    select 0  , 2135 , 'Algeria Cellular-Wataniya'
) cc
join (
    select country_code, country, char_length(rtrim(cast(country_code as char))) as code_len
    from (
        select 93 as country_code, 93  as area_code , 'Afghanistan' as country union
        select 0  , 9375 , 'Afghanistan Cellular-AT' union
        select 0  , 9370 , 'Afghanistan Cellular-AWCC' union
        select 355, 355  , 'Albania' union
        select 0  , 35568, 'Albania Cellular-AMC' union
        select 0  , 35567, 'Albania Cellular-Eagle' union
        select 213, 213  , 'Algeria' union
        select 0  , 21377, 'Algeria Cellular-Djezzy' union
        select 0  , 2135 , 'Algeria Cellular-Wataniya'
    ) c
    where country_code <> 0
) t on 
    t.country_code = cast(substr(cast(cc.area_code as char), 1, t.code_len) as signed integer) and
    cc.country_code = 0 and
    cc.country like concat(t.country, '%')
```

Comment: Thanks Michal I tried, but it gives me this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from country_codes cc join ( select country_code, country, char_length(trim(' at line 3`

Comment: This is the correct approach given that the stated assumptions are correct - you'll just have to play with syntax to make it work.

Comment: @Sachyn do you use this query as is? I have tested it and should work fine. Try my last version maybe something has changed in meantime.

Comment: @MichałPowaga: I am wondering if your query will work in an update?

Comment: @SalmanA yes it will. The first query in my answer (update) is based on the same condition as the second one (select). Select is only for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do the fix the data ONLY once, you can try this approach:

0) Backup your data, or better, run the query on copy of the data.

1) Creates a table that contains non-zero country codes. We need separate table because it says in MySQL manual that:

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in
>   a subquery.

```sql
CREATE TABLE country_codes_list (
    country_code INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO country_codes_list
SELECT country_code
FROM country_codes
WHERE country_code <> 0;
```

2) Update all rows where country code is 0 by finding the country code that matches the beginning of the area code:

```sql
UPDATE country_codes AS country_codes_zero SET country_code = (
    SELECT country_code
    FROM country_codes_list
    WHERE country_codes_list.country_code = SUBSTRING(country_codes_zero.area_code, 1, LENGTH(country_codes_list.country_code))
) WHERE country_code = 0;
```

This could be a very slow query because it uses a co-related sub-query. But it should fix the data in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, assuming you have a database called "testdb", and a table called "footable".

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password1234");
mysql_select_db("testdb", $link);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE footable SET country_code="93" WHERE country LIKE Afghanistan%", $link);
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE footable SET country_code="355" WHERE country LIKE Albania%", $link);

mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: I believe this is the opposite of what @Sachyn is asking for.

Comment: @Adam, There are many more Countries in that table, what he has shown is only sample data.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Consider a case of a row where country is "UK-Orange" and country-code i 0, but the only existing entry is "United Kingdom"... If the data is simple and predictable then automated "guessing" approach can be taken - but this rarely happens in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with `countries` only, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO countries (country_code,country)
SELECT country_code,country FROM country_codes WHERE country_code=0
```

Then you can easily update your table

```
UPDATE country_codes cc, countries c
SET cc.country_code = c.country_code
WHERE LOCATE(c.country,cc.country)=1 AND cc.country_code=0
```

I haven't tested this, but I believe you can get the point.